# Laravel using {id} to for routing the controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I was experimenting the routes.php

```
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    return "'" . ucfirst($id) . 'Controller@' . ucfirst($id) . "'";
});
```

This is the output on the test code above.

'IdController@Id'

I was trying to look it like this

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'IdController@Id');
```

I also tried this ..

```
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    [
        'as' => "'" . $id . "'",
        'uses' => "'" . ucfirst($id) . 'Controller@' . ucfirst($id) . "'"
    ];
});
```

My view is "id.blade.php". Any ideas?

Comment: what problem you are facing??!

Comment: route not in collection . I was able to fix it though i just read the documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App:call('Controller@method',[$id]);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer I was able to fix it though i just read the documentation thoroughly. I will also try your answer if it will shorten the code.